# Create SOAP webservice starting from WSDL using Groovy?

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, groovy

We have a wsdl for which we need to create a server implementation. In previous projects we used wsdl2java from Apache CXF, but now we want to keep it all in Groovy. Is there a way in which we can create a server implementation and keep it all in Groovy? Or are there any other ways we can achieve this?

The ultimate goal would be that we can hook this implementation into a Grails application that will serve as the server for clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can either use the [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cxf) or use [cxf directly](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=85983334).

If you follow that tutorial, you can always use wsdl2java and just rename the generated files to be `.groovy` files and update the syntax to be more *groovified*. They will still work like normal. Also, as you may or may not know, you don't have to copy the jars directly to your lib directory as it says in the tutorial, you can just use normal Grails dependency management.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am not sure what the preferred way would be! Is there a recommendation that can be done? Use the plugin or do it manually? The wsdl contract in my case hase been provided. So my guess is that using it directly would be the preferred way. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I tried to use the cxf direct way, but when i try to run my project it gives me an error:  ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.frontend.spring.ServerFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$SpringServerFactoryBean--230470630': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName

Answer (score 1):

I think a better fit for you would be [Groovy WS Lite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite). [Spring-ws](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/) is also an option, it is a powerful library and reasonably well documented, since grails is spring at the end of day, this may integrate very well with grails. Shameless plug: This is [web service integration testing tool](https://github.com/menacher/Test-Tools) I created which uses groovy and spring-ws. You can see the code to get a "working example".

Comment: Is Groovy WS Lite also capable of providing webservices? I checked GitHub but it only mentions clients. I would be great to have 1 stack for providing and consuming webservices. Spring WS does not seem to be ready for Grails 2 yet.. :( Or am i missing something? Thanks for the suggestions by the way!

Comment: I have used spring-ws in java, groovy projects only not Grails. The plugin page for spring-ws seems outdated http://grails.org/plugin/springws. So, I guess it may not meet your requirements at least for the moment. If you go down this path then the following nabble entry maybe helpful http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-springws-plugin-td1386976.html